# MySql combining results and applying to a second table

Tags: php, mysql

I am having difficulty getting the results from 1 query and making them display in alpha order when the results are numerical.

```
TABLE1: "users" ROWS: user_id, username
TABLE2: "friends" ROWS: user_id, friend_id, confirmed
```

When YOU friend someone or they friend you, and you confirm, you create a "confirmed state" of 1.
With that in mind:

If I make the following query:

```sql
SELECT user_id
  FROM friends
 WHERE friend_id = 4
   AND confirmed = 1
 UNION 
SELECT friend_id
  FROM friends
 WHERE user_id = 4
   AND confirmed=1
```

---

I get a list of all my friends id's. I am user '4'.
What I would like to do now is take this result and look up their usernames from "users" and put them into Alphabetical order to compile a "Friends List"
I've tried all combinations of JOIN etc, but just cant get my head round it.
Please help, Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT u.*
  FROM user u
  JOIN 
     ( SELECT user_id
         FROM friends
        WHERE friend_id = 4
          AND confirmed = 1
        UNION 
       SELECT friend_id
         FROM friends
        WHERE user_id = 4
          AND confirmed=1
    ) x
   ON x.user_id = u.user_id
ORDER
   BY something
```